# preg_match with html tags

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I am trying to get a piece of content out of a website that shows the current status from the server. I did this by the `file_get_content` method. When I try to search through it, i used a  `preg_match` to find the item i want, but it ends up with html tags i cant seem to correctly escape within the code. I get an error W`arning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'B'`. So how do I escape this? and further I missed probably a few functions, but I am not really familair with the RegEx.

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.swgemu.com/forums/content.php');   
$string = '<h3>Basilisk<\/h3><p>Status:<span class=\"online\">Online<\/span>';

if (preg_match($string , $content))
{ echo "The Basilisk server is online"; }
else
{ echo "The Basilisk server is offline";}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to process HTML. Use Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Comment: You are missing delimiters like `#` in `$string`

Comment: Agreed (with @Barmar...). The current problem is caused by missing delimiters though (the regex engine sees the first pair of `<>` as the delimiters).

Comment: So does that mean I have to escape out all the > and <'s within the string or just the first <h3>?

Comment: Nothing to escape just modify it to `$string = '#<h3>Basilisk<\/h3><p>Status:<span class=\"online\">Online<\/span>#';` and take a look at DOM parser.

Comment: @MichalBrašna: in this case, no need to escape double quotes and slashes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a regex. Use a delimiter. Something like this -

```
$string = '/<h3>Basilisk<\/h3><p>Status:<span class=\"online\">Online<\/span>/';
```

Comment: i forgot to add a space after the status:, but it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Better use DOM parsers, but if you really need regex, try to allow spaces:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.swgemu.com/forums/content.php');   
$string = '/<h3>\s*Basilisk\s*<\/h3>\s*<p>\s*Status:\s*<span\s+class=\"online\">\s*Online\s*<\/span>/i';

if (preg_match($string , $content))
{ echo "The Basilisk server is online"; }
else
{ echo "The Basilisk server is offline";}
```

Comment: thanks for the headsup. I ll try to mess with the dom parser as well.